# Appended div disappearing after toggling text inside

Tags: jquery, append, toggle

I have a list of scheduled dates that we toggle the visibility of.  They are loaded as a full list (for non-js fallback) then upon document ready JQuery hides all but the first date, changes the title to Next Date and appends a "show more" div to the parent div of the date list.

The script is set up as a toggle, which shows all dates, changes the title, show more text and then reverts to the hidden version.  The toggle functions for everything work just fine .... EXCEPT .... the appended div disappears when the second toggle function happens.  I am not sure if it being removed or simply hidden.

If I code the show more div into the html it switches, back and forth, as coded.  But as an append it disappears at the end of the toggle.

My html:

```
<div class="title">Scheduled Dates</div>  
<div class="dates">  
<div id="1">23 May 2011</div>  
<div id="2">25 June 2011</div>  
<div id="3">28 Aug 2011</div>  
<div id="4">15 Nov 2011</div>  
</div>
```

The js:

```
$(".dates div:not(#1)").hide();  
$(".title").text("Next Departure");  
$(".dates").append('<div class="datesctrl">show more</div>');  

$(".datesctrl").toggle(function(){  
    $(".dates div").show();  
    $(".datesctrl").text("Show Less");  
    $(".title").text("Scheduled Dates");  

}, function(){  
    $(".dates div:not(#1)").hide();  
    $(".datesctrl").text("Show More");  
    $(".title").text("Next Departure");  

});
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in one of your comments you meant to append "Show More" after dates, which can be done:

```
$(".dates").after('<div class="datesctrl">show more</div>');
```

Just as another suggestion, I recommend changing

```
$(".dates div:not(#1)").hide();
```

to

```
$(".dates div").not(':first-child').hide();
```

it's just a little more readable. Plus it will work with all divs with the class of date.

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/A3fXv/

Comment: More good ideas.  Using .after saves me a few bytes in the html by eliminating the extra wrapper div.

Comment: Tom, after thinking about your problem a little, consider checking out this: http://jsfiddle.net/A3fXv/2/ it would more easily allow you to have multiple "dates" divs on the same page, which is actually somewhat difficult with the current setup. If nothing else it will just give you some other tools to use in your jQuery travels.

Comment: Thanks for the extra code ideas, the more I see the more I learn.  This project has only the one list we are manipulating.

Answer (score 0):

Your appended `div` is being matched by the `$(".dates div:not(#1)")` selector in the hide callback.

Comment: I thought the div:not(#1) applied only to divs inside dates or is the appended div being added inside dates ?  Did I append it wrong ?

Comment: Yes you are appending the div inside of dates.

Comment: OK, I wrapped the dates inside another div and it works.  Thanks to both of you !